# Paypal Advanced Testing without Paypal Manager account

Tags: paypal

i have sandbox account.
i need to create Secure Token ID and Secure Token to test paypal advanced ,
where to get Secure Token ID and Secure Token?
is manager account is must needed for testing ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for implementing Secure token you need to have a manger account with payflow link or paylfow pro.

[Sign up](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/payflow-compare-pricing)

You can run the transactions in manager account with test(similar to sandbox in paypal)

Comment: I created but where can i see the secure token and secure Token ID ?!

Comment: You need to create a secure token(a random 16 digit characters) and send to payflow server and server would return you back with the secure token id which you use to make your transaction.

Comment: may i get it through HTTP POST ? i think i need to pass my credentials to https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com ?!

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

this will give you more idea

basically pass the credentials to pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com